# How do I get all the text between the last two instances of a token in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, sed, awk

I’m using bash and running the following command to get all the file text between two tokens (including the tokens themselves):

```
cat /usr/java/jboss/standalone/log/server.log | sed -n \
'/Starting deployment of "myproject.war"/,/Registering web context: \/myproject/p'
```

However, sometimes the tokens occur multiple times in the file.  How do I adjust the above so that only the text between the last two occurrences of the tokens (including the tokens themselves) will be returned?

Comment: what are the two tokens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution is not efficient, but easier to understand:

```
file='/usr/java/jboss/standalone/log/server.log'

s1='Starting deployment of "myproject.war"'
s2='Registering web context: \/myproject'

sed -n '/'"$s1"'/,/'"$s2"'/p' "$file" | 
  tac | 
  awk '/'"$s1"'/ {print;exit} 1' | 
  tac
```

- Lets `sed` report ALL ranges first.
- Reverses the result using `tac` (on OSX, use `tail -r`).
- Using `awk`, outputs everything up to and including the first occurrence of the first substring, which - in the reversed result - spans the end of the last range to the start of the last range.
- Reverses the output from `awk` to render the last range in correct order.

Note: For consistency with the variable use in the `sed` command I've spliced a variable reference directly into the `awk` program, too, which is otherwise poor practice (use `-v` to pass variables instead).

Answer (score 1):

How about some `tic-tac-toe`.

```
tac /usr/java/jboss/standalone/log/server.log | 
awk '/Registering web context: \/myproject/{p=1;++cnt}/Starting deployment of "myproject.war"/{if(cnt==2){print $0;exit};print $0;p=0}p' |
tac
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me.  Perhaps because I combined everything into a single line -- tac /usr/java/jboss/standalone/log/server.log | awk '/Registering web context: \/myproject/{++p}/Starting deployment of “myproject.war"/{if(p==2) {print $0;exit}}p' | tac > /tmp/output, but the first line of the /tmp/output file is the first line of my server.log file, which doesn't include the start token I want.

Comment: @Dave Aah, I found a bug in the script. Can you try the update please?

Answer (score 0):

This awk can work:

```
awk '/Starting deployment of "myproject.war"/{i=0; s=1; delete a;}
   s{a[++i]=$0}
   /Registering web context: \/myproject/{s=0}
   END {print i; for (k=1; k<=i; k++) print a[k]}' file
```

Comment: I just tried this, but no output was produced, despite the fact I verified the tokens are present multiple times in the file.

Comment: If you provide a sample of your log file I can check.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in native bash -- no need for awk, tac, or any other external tool.

```
token1='Starting deployment of "myproject.war"'
token2='Registering web context: /myproject/'
writing=0
while read -r; do
  (( ! writing )) && [[ $REPLY = $token1 ]] && {
    # start collecting content, into an empty buffer, when we see token1
    writing=1                    # set flag to store lines we see
    collected_content=()         # clear the array of lines found so far
  }
  (( writing )) && {
    # when the flag is set, collect content into an array
    collected_content+=( "$REPLY" )
  }
  [[ $REPLY = $token2 ]] && {
    # stop collecting content when we see token2
    writing=0
  }
done <server.log # redirect from the log into the loop

# print all collected lines
printf '%s\n' "${collected_content[@]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

With `perl`:

```
perl -0xFF -nE '@x = /WWWW Starting deployment of "myproject.war"(.*?)Registering web context: \/myproject/sg; say $x[-1] ' file
```